# Is there a way to transform a png icon to a sf multipolygon in R?

Tags: r, leaflet, r-sf

I would like to merge a layer of this ship icon to my shapefile. I would like to transform in a multipolygon sf... There is a way?

[image: ship_icon]

Comment: Seems possible but probably cumbersome. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Inkscape has a function to trace bitmaps - https://inkscape.org/doc/tutorials/tracing/tutorial-tracing.html - which will give you a starting point of coordinates to work with.

Comment: @camille, yes i think it's cumbersome too. haha. I have a shp file with territories and i need a ocean territory as a ship haha

Comment: @thelatemail, thankyou i will try.

Comment: Even better, that image is already available as an SVG - https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/sea-ship-with-containers_46053

Comment: @thelatemail, ok, but now i need to transform in multipolygon sf. haha

Answer (score 4):

Here's two options:

###### 1) Convert like-colours to polygons

First, import the file using `terra::rast()` and keep the first three layers (red, green, blue).

```
library(terra)
library(tmap)
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

rast('my_ship.png') %>% 
  .[[1:3]] %>% 
  {. ->> my_ship}

my_ship

# class       : SpatRaster 
# dimensions  : 630, 1200, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
# resolution  : 0.0008333333, 0.001587302  (x, y)
# extent      : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
# source      : my_ship.png 
# names       : my__1, my__2, my__3
```

We can look at the actual values, and see that just about all values are either 0 or 255

```
my_ship %>% 
  hist
```

[image]

So, if we round all values to the nearest 255, using `plyr::round_any()`, we will have distinct areas of 0 or 255.

```
my_ship %>% 
  app(fun = function(x) plyr::round_any(x, 255)) %>% 
  {. ->> my_ship_rounded}

my_ship_rounded

# class       : SpatRaster 
# dimensions  : 630, 1200, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
# resolution  : 0.0008333333, 0.001587302  (x, y)
# extent      : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
# source      : memory 
# names       : my__1, my__2, my__3 
# min values  :     0,     0,     0 
# max values  :   255,   255,   255
```

Then, we can use `terra::as.polygons()` to convert groups of cells with the same value to a polygon (initially `SpatVector` and then to `sf`).

```
my_ship_rounded %>% 
  as.polygons %>% 
  st_as_sf %>%
  rename(
    value = 1
  ) %>% 
  {. ->> my_ship_multipoly}

my_ship_multipoly

# Simple feature collection with 2 features and 1 field
# Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 1 ymax: 1
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#   value                       geometry
# 1     0 MULTIPOLYGON (((0.5841667 0...
# 2   255 MULTIPOLYGON (((0.315 0.617...
```

```
tm_shape(my_ship_multipoly)+
  tm_polygons(col = 'value', style = 'cat')
```

[image]

I must admit, the ship looks a little squashed compared to the original, and I'm not sure if that's just the way it's plotted or if it has become skewed somewhere.

###### 2) Extract contour lines

We use `terra::as.contour()` to find contour lines in the ship raster. Again, because most values are either 0 or 255, we choose to extract the contour of line 250, then convert the `SpatVector` of lines to `sf`, and cast from `MULTILINESTRING` to `MULTIPOLYGON`.

```
my_ship %>% 
  as.contour(level = 250) %>%
  st_as_sf %>% 
  st_cast('MULTIPOLYGON') %>% 
  {. ->> my_ship_contour_250}
  
my_ship_contour_250

# Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 1 field
# Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 0.243752 ymin: 0.1544837 xmax: 0.7560956 ymax: 0.845523
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#   level                       geometry
# 1   250 MULTIPOLYGON (((0.2459954 0...
```

And plot it

```
my_ship_contour_250 %>% 
  tm_shape()+
  tm_polygons()
```

[image]

I guess this example is made easy because the image is coloured (mostly) either black or white; we are able to find contour lines or rasterize based on only a single layer. This would get a bit trickier with more complex colours. Also, I'm not sure why the plots look squashed, or of this matters - maybe someone can shed some light here if it is a problem.

---

*UPDATE 2022-02-07*

I figured out the reason the ship looks squished is because the aspect ratio of the image (1200 x 630) doesn't match that of the default extent of `rast()` (which is 1:1). So, to make the ship the right shape you can assign the extent like so:

```
rast('my_ship.png') %>% 
  .[[1:3]] %>% 
  `ext<-`(c(0, 1200, 0, 630)) %>% 
  {. ->> my_ship}
```

However, something along the line changes and `tmap` won't plot it because of invalid geometries. However, the `MULTIPOLYGON` can still be visualised using `plot()`:

[image]